# centos 6.4 nat virtual machines not able to connect to the internet

Tags: iptables, nat

I have two virtual machines running on virtual box. The master has one interface(eth0) bridged to the host nic(eth0) and another one connected to the internal network(eth1). This acts as a gateway to the internal network. The second virtual machine is connected to the internal network only (using eth0).

I cant seem to access the internet from the second virtual machine nor can i do ping -I eth1 8.8.8.8 for example.

Here is the script i use to setup nat

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong please help.

Sources:

1. http://linuxers.org/howto/how-set-nat-linux-using-iptables
2. http://www.centos.org/docs/4/4.5/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html

Comment: What is the output of 'route -n'?

Comment: route -n is showing the gateway as 10.1.1.1 (which is correct). I can ping both the interfaces on master (10.1.1.1 and 192.168.1.45).
I cant however ping the machine that is hosting the virtual machines (192.168.1.43) nor can i ping 8.8.8.8. Both result in ping returning destination host prohibited.

Comment: Hello, i disabled iptables on the server and rebooted the machine, ran the nat script posted above and everything works perfectly :)
thanks for your help.